# New to SQL- Delete First and Last Day of Each Month From Data Set

Tags: sql-server

I am extremely new to SQL. I am operating on SQL Server 2012.

I am working with an Inventory file that contains the Date the Inventory was taken, item #, and quantity. The first and last day of each month of the data set is wrong. My goal is to remove just the rows that contain the first and last day of each month. Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104573/i-have-a-years-worth-of-inventory-data-and-i-want-to-extract-the-first-and-las) (asked and answered only 6 hours ago). The responses should help you formulate a query (I don't run or know much about SQL Server - last ran it over a decade ago!).

Answer (score 0):

What datatype is the Date column ?
How many years of data does it contain?
Are the time values 'midnight' time, like '2015-05-01 00:00:00.000'?

Just to give you an idea :

```
select * from Inventory where Date in ('2015-01-01','2015-01-31','2015-02-01','2015-02-28', ..similarly each month-start and month-end.., '2015-12-01','2015-12-28')
```